# One SVG class hover can affect another SVG element

Tags: css, svg, text, hover, rect

On this [page](http://chemistrytable.dx.am/index_eng_tabled.php), I have chemical table in SVG code and the chemical elements are in rect tag. The names of the elements within the rect tag are in text tag.

I require that when a mouse is over the text tag, then the stroke-width of the rect gets bigger as well.

Now, what I have achieved is, making the rect:hover change the stroke-width property of the rect. Combining the two, doesn't do this, since text doesn't have stroke-width property.

```
text:hover, rect:hover  {
opacity:1;
stroke-width:3;
cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: I suspect you merely want to make the text pointer-events: none; then just implement hover for the rect elements. A [mcve] would help here really.

Comment: Thanks. Brilliant!